# Heroku npm bower issue mean stack app

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, bower

I keep trying to push to heroku with no success. I have tried modifying the .gitignore file, sticking to node version 10, clearing npm cache, trying to stage instead of production, getting frustrated please help!

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Resetting git environment
-----> Requested node range:  0.10.x
-----> Resolved node version: 0.10.35
-----> Downloading and installing node
-----> Found existing node_modules directory; skipping cache
-----> Rebuilding any native dependencies
       npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client/node_modules/request/node_modules/node-uuid/bin/uuid'
       npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
       npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
       npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

       npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
       npm ERR! command "/tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/vendor/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/vendor/node/bin/npm" "rebuild"
       npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a
       npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
       npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
       npm ERR! path /tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client/node_modules/request/node_modules/node-uuid/bin/uuid
       npm ERR! code ENOENT
       npm ERR! errno 34
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/npm-debug.log
       npm ERR! not ok code 0
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/vendor/node/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/vendor/node/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'rebuild' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.28
3 info using node@v0.10.35
4 info readInstalled object
5 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a', 'cake@1.0.0' ]
6 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/node_modules/bower',
6 verbose rebuild   'bower@1.3.12' ]
7 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/node_modules/bower/node_modules/abbrev',
7 verbose rebuild   'abbrev@1.0.5' ]
8 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/node_modules/bower/node_modules/archy',
8 verbose rebuild   'archy@0.0.2' ]
9 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config',
9 verbose rebuild   'bower-config@0.5.2' ]
10 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config/node_modules/graceful-fs',
10 verbose rebuild   'graceful-fs@2.0.3' ]
11 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout',
11 verbose rebuild   'mout@0.9.1' ]
.......

667 verbose linkMans node-uuid@1.4.2
668 verbose rebuildBundles node-uuid@1.4.2
669 error Error: ENOENT, chmod '/tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client/node_modules/request/node_modules/node-uuid/bin/uuid'
670 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
670 error including the npm and node versions, at:
670 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
671 error System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
672 error command "/tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/vendor/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/vendor/node/bin/npm" "rebuild"
673 error cwd /tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a
674 error node -v v0.10.35
675 error npm -v 1.4.28
676 error path /tmp/build_b8036af8fa11d1792ae4d166a4eaaf9a/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client/node_modules/request/node_modules/node-uuid/bin/uuid
677 error code ENOENT
678 error errno 34
679 verbose exit [ 34, true ]

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

Comment: Have you been able to clear out the `existing node_modules directory`?

Comment: Hard to say based on just these error logs. Did you include a Procfile in the app and explicitly state your nose version in package.json?

Comment: @generalhenry let me try that

Comment: @JamesP yes, and explicitly state the npm version as well to no avail...